# Prove that $\det(A^n)=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, determinant

If

$$A= \left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & \sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta & \cos \theta \end{array}\right]$$

Then prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\det(A^n)=1$.

Comment: Are you aware that the determinant function is multiplicative?  I.e. $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ for all matrices $A, B \in M_{n \times n}( \mathbb{R})$.  Apply this to the problem at hand.  What is $\det(A)$?

Comment: You should add your own thoughts and attempts. People will be more inclined to help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

**Method -1:** $\mathrm{det}(A^n)=(\mathrm{det}(A))^n=1$

**Method -2:** $A \in  \mathbb{SO}(2)$, $A^n \in \mathbb{SO}(2) \implies \mathrm{det}(A^n)=1$

**Method -3:** $A^n = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos (n\theta) & \sin (n\theta)\\ -\sin (n\theta) & \cos (n\theta) \end{array}\right] \implies \mathrm{det}(A^n) = 1$ [Induction or from simple geometry.]

Comment: Use enclosing enclosing brackets instead of enclosing bars for matrices.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $\det(A^n)=(\det(A))^n$, true for all square matrix $A$ and natural number $n$

Answer (score 0):

Just another method, just for the fun of it.

Notice that the following $K =  \{M = 
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
a && b \\
-b && a \\
\end{array} } \right] $ | a, b $\in \mathbb{R}$ } is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Notice now that the set $K' =  \{M = 
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
cos(\theta) && sin(\theta) \\
-sin(\theta) && cos(\theta) \\
\end{array} } \right] $ | a, b $\in \mathbb{R}$ } is isomorphic to the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ consistint of all elements of the form $cos(\theta) + isin(\theta)$.

That is, $K'$ is the complex unity circle.

Show that if $A \in K$, then $det(A)$ is the norm of the complex number associated to $A$ squared.

Prove now that if two complex elements are on the unity circle, then their product is also in the unity circle.

Now, all elements of the unity circle have norm 1.

Suppose $A \in K'$. Then $A^n \in K'$. Then the complex element associated to $A^n$ has norm one. Conclude now that $det(A^n) = 1$

I still think you should simply use the fact that $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$ though.

Good luck!